# 0 second load time for Admob Ads in Android

Tags: android, admob

The question is in the context of Admob in Android.

In every activity, the admob ads is taking couple of seconds to load. I want that the Admob Ads should load instantly with the activity.

I have tried couple of solutions but nothing seems to work :(

So i thought of Frameset concept in HTML, if we click on the link, in a particular frame then only that part will refresh and the other part remains static.

So i was hoping for similar solutions in Android, where the admob ads remain static and the rest part of my activity changes accordingly.
Can anyone guide me, on how to implement similar functionality in Android ?

Also if you have any other alternative to the Admob Ads 0 seconds load time, kindly share it.

Answer (score 1):

Admob takes about a couple of seconds because instruction to load admob is called only when activity started. That's why every admob is also reloaded as long as you reload your activity. In addition, this is often a remote call and could take a time. 
Solution :

- Create a main activity (which contain admob loading) which handle your set of fragments. I mean instead of using activities, you should use fragments handled by only one activity.
- So, you can navigate between all of your views using fragment manager without making any change to admob loading (because it owns to main activity)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Can kindly suggest me a reference link (preferable source code), from which i can easily take up stuffs.